# How to perform date comparisons against postgres with sequelize

Tags: javascript, postgresql, date, sequelize.js

I want to delete all records with dates before 20 minutes ago. Postgres (or Sequelize) is not satisfied with the bare javascript `Date` object I provide as the comparison value.

I'm using sequelize 4.37 on top of a postgres 9.6 database.

The column in question was declared with `type: Sequelize.DATE`, which research suggests is equivalent to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`: a full date and time with microsecond precision and a timezone signifier. (That is also what I see when I use the psql CLI tool to describe the table.)

So, I do this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const { SomeModel } = require('../models.js')

// calculate 20 minutes ago
async function deleteStuff() {
  const deletionCutoff = new Date()
  deletionCutoff.setMinutes( deletionCutoff.getMinutes() - 20 ) 

  await SomeModel.destroy({
    where: {
      [ Sequelize.Op.lt ]: { dateColumn: deletionCutoff }
    }
  })
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid value { dateColumn: 2018-11-21T21:26:16.849Z }
```

The docs suggest I should be able to provide either a bare javascript Date, or an ISO8601 string, but both throw the same `Invalid Value` error. The only difference is that, if I pass a string, the error shows single quotes around the value:

```
// error when dateColumn: deletionCutoff.toISOString()
Error: Invalid value { dateColumn: '2018-11-21T21:26:16.849Z' }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is pretty embarrassing. I structured the `where` clause incorrectly.

```js
// BAD CODE
await SomeModel.destroy({
    where: {
        [ Sequelize.Op.lt ]: {
            dateColumn: deletionCutoff
        }
    }
})


// GOOD CODE
await SomeModel.destroy({
    where: {
        dateColumn: {
            [ Sequelize.Op.lt ]: deletionCutoff
        }
    }
})
```

Maybe I should delete the question. Maybe not -- the error I got probably could be more helpful.

Comment: You can also accept your answer. I think it's useful. ;-)

Comment: Had to wait 2 days. Still might delete it... we'll see how much hate it collects.

Comment: Yeah @Tom theres a reason you structured it wrong also a reason I structured it wrong and its likely the docs.