# Sequelize: Date Comparison Inside of an AND Block

Tags: postgresql, datetime, sequelize.js

I hammered on this for hours -- trying to get a date comparison working inside of an `and` block. Both parts baffled me for a while -- the date comparison part, and the `and` syntax.

This is the syntax that did not work - then I'll post the answer with the code that does work.

Note: `user_presence_time_of_last_update` is a field of type `time stamp with timezone`.

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
const op = connectors.Sequelize.Op;
const timeTwoHoursAgo = new Date()
timeTwoHoursAgo.setMinutes(timeTwoHoursAgo.getMinutes() - 120)

var usersWhoWentOffline = connectors.epUserData.findAll({
    where: {
        $and:{
            user_presence_time_of_last_update: {$lt: new Date(new Date() - 5 * one_hour)},
            $or:[
                {user_presence: USER_PRESENCE_IDLE},
                {user_presence: USER_PRESENCE_ONLINE},
            ],
        }
    }
}).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code that does work, with a big assist from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420866/how-to-perform-date-comparisons-against-postgres-with-sequelize):

**DOES WORK**

```
const op = connectors.Sequelize.Op;
const timeTwoHoursAgo = new Date()
timeTwoHoursAgo.setMinutes(timeTwoHoursAgo.getMinutes() - 120)

var usersWhoWentOffline = connectors.epUserData.findAll({
    where: {
        [op.and]: {
            user_presence_time_of_last_update: {
                [op.lt]: timeTwoHoursAgo
            },
            [op.or]: [
                {user_presence: USER_PRESENCE_IDLE},
                {user_presence: USER_PRESENCE_ONLINE},
            ]
        }
    }
})
```